# Reflection.Emit with generic type = type is not generic

Tags: c#, generics, reflection.emit

I am using Refletion.Emit, I have an interface, an abstract class and another class. What I want to achieve is create a new class based on those two. 
So here is the simple interface:

```
public interface IHello()
{     
    string SayHello(); 
}
```

This is my abstract class:

```
public abstract class Helloer<T> where T : IHello, new()
{
        private readonly string text;

        protected Helloer(string text)
        {
            this.text = text;                
        }

        public string DoIt()
        {
            var t = new T();
            return t.SayHello() + text;
        }
}
```

and the second class:

```
public class Howdy : IHello
{
        public string SayHello() { return "Howdy"; }
}
```

Now this is the full main code responsible for creating the new type HowdyHelloer:

```
public static void Run()
    {
        var type = CreateHelloer(typeof(Howdy));
        dynamic helloer = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        Console.WriteLine(helloer.DoIt());
    }


    public static Type CreateHelloer(Type hello)
    {
        var assemblyBuilder = GetAssemblyBuilder("MyAssembly");
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(hello.Name + "Helloer", TypeAttributes.Public);
        var parentType = typeof(Helloer<>).MakeGenericType(hello);  

        typeBuilder.SetParent(parentType);
        Type[] types = new Type[1];
        types[0] = typeof(string);
        var parentCtorGeneric1 = typeof(Helloer<>).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, types, null);


        var parentCtor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(parentType, parentCtorGeneric1);
        var ctor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { });
        var ctorIl = ctor.GetILGenerator();
        ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Partner");
        ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, parentCtor);
        ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }

    public static AssemblyBuilder GetAssemblyBuilder(string name)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(name);
        var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AssemblyBuilder c =  domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        return c;
    }
```

On the line:

```
var parentCtor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(parentType, parentCtorGeneric1);
```

I'm getting an error: " 'type' must contain a TypeBuilder as a generic argument."
Can anyone help me with this please? As I'm trying to solve this for last 3 days and nothing :/ I did research and to be honest I didn't found anything specific on using Emit with generic abstract classes.

Comment: what you try do with this line `var parentCtor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(parentType, parentCtorGeneric1);`? in [msdn TypeBuilder.GetConstructor Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145822(v=vs.110).aspx) _The constructed generic type whose constructor is returned._ but you try pass not constructed type

Comment: anyway you wrong create constructor for created type

Comment: Can you then tell me/explain how this should be done properly?

Comment: i'm added answer, possibly it help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i see in your code at least two error

first:

```
var parentCtor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(parentType, parentCtorGeneric1);
```

here `parentType` was not created with `TypeBuilder`, so if you want get parent constuctor just get it from parent type like

```
var parentCtorGeneric1 = parentType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, types, null);
```

second: you wrong create consctuctor code, it should like this

```
var ctorIl = ctor.GetILGenerator();
ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // show where to load the following string
ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Partner");
ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, parentCtorGeneric1);
ctorIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```